# jqgrid: how best to handle the effects of showing/hiding columns

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

Currently, I'm getting data for a jqgrid using

```
datatype: function(postdata) {}
```

Based on the data I get back, I dynamically show/hide certain columns. I'm also using:

```
shrinkToFit: false
```

I am not setting a grid width.  Instead, I'm letting the explicit column widths determine the width of the grid.

The grid size is computed when the grid is initially displayed.  If I then hide a column, the grid is rendered with blank space on the right.  If I show more columns than were originally rendered, the grid is displayed with a horizontal scroll bar.

I need to be able to do one of the following:

- Hide the grid until after all columns are shown or hidden, then
  display the grid with the proper width (no white space or scroll
  bars)
- Recalculate the grid width after the columns are hidden or shown.

How would I accomplish either?

Answer (score 0):

I found out how to resolve the issue.  Previously I was calling the following:

```
var thegrid = j$(thisGridId)[0];
thegrid.addJSONData(json);
```

and then showing/hiding columns.

I changed my code so that I first show/hide columns and then call addJSONData().  Problem solved.